# is it possible to use a lambda instead of a class in c++?

Tags: c++, lambda

I have recently been reading a design patterns book written for Java, but I am actually interested in applying the techniques to C++, so I am "translating" the examples from Java to C++. I found out that in Java, it is possible to use a lambda expression as a parameter of a function instead of an object (instance of a class). With my current C++ knowledge, I have not found a way to do something equivalent or similar using C++, I don't even know if that is possible, so I give it a try here.

In Java:

```java
public class Light {
    public void on()
    {
        //whatever
    }
    public void off()
    {
        //whatever
    }
}

public interface Command {
    public virtual void execute();
};

public class RemoteControl {

    Command m_command;

    public RemoteControl() {}

    public void setCommand(Command command)
    {
        m_command = command;
    }
}
```

According to the book, in Java, given the characteristics of the interface (just one method), it is possible to use a lambda with the signature of the method declared in the interface instead of an "instance" of the interface, eg:

```java
RemoteControl remoteControl;
Light livingRoomLight;
remoteControl.setCommand( ()->{livingRoomLight.on();} );
```

**What can I do in C++ to achieve something similar?**

My current C++ code:

```cpp
class Light
{
public:
    Light() {}

    void on()
    {
        //whatever
    }

    void off()
    {
        //whatever
    }
};

class Command  
{
public:
    virtual ~Command() = default;
    virtual void execute() = 0;
};

class RemoteControl
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Command> m_command = {nullptr};

public:

    RemoteControl() {}

    void setCommand(std::shared_ptr<Command> command)
    {
        m_command = command;
    }
};
```

**Is it possible in C++ to use a lambda expression instead of a pointer to a `Command` instance?**

Something like:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<RemoteControl> remoteControl = std::make_unique<RemoteControl>();
std::shared_ptr<Light> livingRoomLight = std::make_shared<Light>();

remoteControl->setCommand( [livingRoomLight](){ livingRoomLight->on(); );
```

or

```cpp
RemoteControl* remoteControl = new RemoteControl;
Light* livingRoomLight = new Light;

std::function<void()> livingRoomLightOn = [livingRoomLight]() { livingRoomLight->on(); };

remoteControl->setCommand( &livingRoomLightOn );
```

Answer (score 3):

It's possible, but your syntax is wrong.  Here's an example of how to do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Light
{
public:
    void on () { std::cout << "Light on\n"; }
    void off () { std::cout << "Light of\n"; }
};

class RemoteControl
{
public:
    void setCommand (std::function <void ()> command)
    {
        m_command = command;
    }
    
    void performCommand () { m_command (); }

private:
    std::function <void ()> m_command;
};

int main ()
{
    Light livingRoomLight;
    RemoteControl remoteControl;

    remoteControl.setCommand ([&livingRoomLight] () { livingRoomLight.on (); });
    remoteControl.performCommand ();
}
```

Output:

```
Light on
```

Note that `livingRoomLight` is passed to the lambda by reference so that it can modify the original object.

Comment: For this particular case, the living room light should be passed by reference.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Good point, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Using an `std::function` as a parameter is expensive, and should generally be discouraged. The parameter should be a templated, and an `std::function` used only for storing the closure (there are a few cases where this adds enough difficulty to justify using an `std::function`, but that doesn't seem to be the case here).

Comment: @JerryCoffin I don't see the value in using a template here.  Surely the whole point is that you can store different `command`s in `remoteControl` at different times, and a template can't do that.

Comment: @PaulSanders: I don't think it's at all obvious that that would be the intent at all. And even assuming that is what's desired, passing the parameter as a template type certainly doesn't prevent doing that.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Perhaps I didn't make myself clear.  What I meant was, it looks like the OP wants to store different `command`s in _the same_ `remoteControl` at different times.  If he doesn't, then there's no point to any of this.

Comment: @PaulSanders: I'm still not convinced that's true. And you can still use a template for the argument type to do that (hint: member template).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pass a lambda<sup>1</sup>, but since each lambda expression creates a new, unique type (and you don't know the name of that type) you have<sup>2</sup> to use a template parameter for the type of the lambda:

```cpp
template <class Command>
class RemoteControl {
    std::function<void()> command;
public:
    RemoteControl(Command const &command) : command(command) {}
    void operator() { command(); }
};

int main() { 
    Light light;
    RemoteControl turnOn([&] mutable { light.on(); });
    RemoteControl turnOff([&] mutable { light.off(); });

    // ...

    turnOn(); // invoke the remote control to turn on the light

    // ...
    turnOff(); // invoke the other remote control to turn off the light
}
```

I would urge that this be used with caution though. In particular, you're basically using a rather complex, roundabout way of creating something equivalent to just having the `Light` as a simple variable, with a couple of free functions to manipulate it:

```cpp
bool light; // probably not the real type, but it'll do for now

void turnOn() { light = true; }
void turnOff() { light = false; }
```

Java doesn't allow free functions, so you have to use this roundabout way to imitate them. C++ doesn't restrict you that way, so if you have control of the code that's currently embodied in the `Light` class, and you want it to act like a simple variable that's manipulated by free functions, then you should probably do that directly.

---

1. Well, technically, what you're passing is a "closure". A "lambda expression" basically refers to syntax in the source code. The "thing" that's created by the lambda expression is the closure--but unless you're exceptionally anal, don't worry about it--most people would use "lambda" exactly like you did.
2. Well, technically, you don't have to. You can use an `std::function` instead--but as a rule, you should use a template type for the parameter itself. `std::function` should be used only for *storing* the lambda (if you need to do that).

Comment: You don't HAVE to use a template....  std::function<> works fine as well.  The problem with templates, is that a new function is generated for each call to the template function, this contributes to code bloat.  On the other hand, using std::function MAY prevent the compiler to inline small functions properlyk, resulting in performance loss.  As with any engineering choice, there are trade-offs one needs to be aware of, before choosing a solution.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy: No, you don't have to (thus my second foot note, specifically pointing out that it isn't an absolute requirement). As for "code bloat"--feel free to show a demonstration of its happening. People have been claiming this for a decade now, but I've yet to see anybody demonstrate it (and it hasn't happened in my testing either).

Comment: For code bloat, all you need to do is check the output assembly code.  The amount of bloat will depend on the amount and complexity of code involved, size of the function, size of lambdas, and number of calls with different lambdas.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy: Not true. You have to look at the code after it's been linked (linkers do more than you realize). This problem first arose when templates were added, and people noticed that (for example) `vector<int>` and `vector<unsigned>` produced separate (but identical) sequences of code for essentially all operations. By the late 1990's, they'd rewritten linkers so those separate sequences got merged together. The same works fine for lambdas as well. The problem you're claiming to happen from lambdas had actually been fixed 12-15 years before C++ had lambdas at all.

Comment: Read resulting compiled assembly code. Each template instantiation results in a different function.  As soon as the code gets complex enough, the compiler cannot inline the tempate instantiations and will generate a different copy for each instantiation.  That's a secret to no one.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy: What's apparently a secret from you (even though I just told you about it) is that a linker can look at those separate code sequences, "see" that they're actually identical, and merge them together. This was true long before lambdas were added to the language. And no, the compiler doesn't need to inline *anything* for this to happen.

Comment: Except that, since the lambdas are different, the code is NOT identical.  The linker cannot optimize fractions of a function.  And one shoul never rely on compiler optiization to write good code.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy: There are cases where the code *can* be different, but *just* being different types doesn't mean that copying objects is different. I pointed this out roughly an hour ago, pointing to `vector<int>` vs. vector<unsigned>`. `foo.push_back(bar);` Signed and unsigned int are different types, but the code to push back them is identical (e.g. `mov rax, rbx` will copy rbx to rax, regardless of whether you think of that value as signed or unsigned). In the case of a lambda, you're copying an object. The fact that `operator()` is overloaded differently in each doesn't affect copying.

Comment: Copying is affected when the *members* of the objects are different.In the case of lambdas, it could become interesting when they capture different things, and (for example) one captures something that has a copy ctor, while the other captures something that allows bitwise copy. But, in the case at hand, they both capture the same object, so that whole line of discussion is utterly irrelevant (and in the rare case that it becomes a problem, you still usually want to use a template parameter, but pass by reference rather than value).